# Install and set Path for Oracle Java JDK 16 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, java, oracle

I have installed Oracle JDK 16 on Ubuntu 20.04.
I have downloaded the tar.gz file and installed it using the ubuntu software installer and its confirmed to be installed in the ubuntu software center.

Using "java" in the terminal returns "command not found".

I assume the path is not set correctly.
I set the path according to this:
https://java.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-install-java-16-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts

However my JDK got installed in "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1"

So I added

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH

to my /etc/profile

I am but still getting "Command 'java' not found".

Any Ideas, what I did wrong?

Comment: Silly question, but have you reloaded your profile since adding the path? You can do this by closing and re-opening Terminal 

Comment: "Unfortunately" yes I did. I even did a full restart without any result.

Comment: Please go to section '# Configure Java Alternatives'  https://java.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-install-java-16-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts  and do the two install commands .... and finally, if required,  the --config command : To select version.

Comment: This solved it, thank you!